# Placing buttons in square in a mobile page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am developing a mobile web page. I need to place four buttons in a square way:

|  btn1   |   btn2|

|  btn3   |   btn4|

Each one of these button must be placed in its own div, like this:

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <div class="btn1">
       <!-- button -->
    </div>
    <div class="btn2">
       <!-- button -->
    </div>
    <div class="btn3">
       <!-- button -->
    </div>
    <div class="btn4">
       <!-- button -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: _"I need to place four buttons in a square way"._ What?

Comment: Do you have any CSS that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current html I would recommend using something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qurquLe/

each button needs to be 50% and floated left. make sure the container is set to 100%.

```
.buttonContainer {
    width:100%;
}
.buttonContainer div {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: `make sure the container is set to 100%`   .buttonContainer is a div, div element is block element and that means width is always 100%. nosense

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flex` like this:

```css
div.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
} 
div.buttonContainer div {  
  flex:1 0 auto;
  
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
<div class="btn1">
   <!-- button -->
</div>
<div class="btn2">
   <!-- button -->
</div>
<div class="btn3">
   <!-- button -->
</div>
<div class="btn4">
   <!-- button -->
</div>
</div>
```